# 404 pages displaying name of page

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

My website works great; Google Cloud Platform VM running Ubuntu and Apache2. Well, except for one thing; I can't get 404 pages to work. I followed several guides and managed to do something *really* dumb.

This is the result of a 404:

[image: 404 Error Document]

This is the actual 404 document (the contents of `/404.html`):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>404</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>404 :(</h1>
This page doesn't exist. Sorry!
<br><br>
You can <button onclick="history.back();">Go back</button>,
jump to the <a href="/">Site root</a>, or the <a href="/kcp">KCP root</a>.
</body>
```

I've deleted every `.htaccess` file and every `ErrorDocument ...` line I can find, trying to restore the default behavior.

**UPDATE:** Found the errant line, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you are seeing is consistent with having defined the 404 `ErrorDocument` like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "404.html"
```

By surrounding the 2nd argument in quotes you define the "error document" as a simple string. The server is still responding with a 404 HTTP status code.

Whereas it should be something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

> I've deleted every `.htaccess` file and every `ErrorDocument ...` line I can find

If you have access to the server config, then the server config would be a more usual place for this. In which case, you would need to restart your server for any changes to take effect.

Or, the response is cached server-side / proxy?

---

**UPDATE:** If you can't find where this is being set, then (as a workaround) you should be able to redefine the `ErrorDocument` correctly in `.htaccess` and this should override any setting in parent `.htaccess` files or the server config. (This is providing `AllowOverride FileInfo` - or greater - is set in the server config, permitting the setting of `ErrorDocument` in `.htaccess` in the first place.)

Comment: Which server config file do you want me to look at?

Comment: Which config files have you changed? :) The main config file is often called `httpd.conf` (or `apache2.conf`, or _something else_). You might also have separate `Include` files that are included in the main config. You might also have a separate config file for your virtual hosts (or even a separate file for each virtual host)?

Comment: Note that if you cannot find where this is defined then you should be able to define the `ErrorDocument` again in `.htaccess` to override this. I've updated my answer.